# How do you actually see the html output during a functional test in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One of my assert_selects is driving me up the wall. Its failing and of course its telling me what it expected but Id like to see what was actually there on that page when it rendered to track down this bug.

Ive already tried using my browser and the app is behaving as it should but thats using development data.

Is there a command i can use to print the html to console or my test log?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just do

```
puts @response.body
```

right before the problematic assertion and you should see the thing.

Answer (score 2):

[Webrat](http://github.com/brynary/webrat) does this very thing with the command `save_and_open_page`.

Answer (score 2):

on a Rails 5.x environment, using parsed_body worked for me, while just plain body did not:

```
puts @response.parsed_body
```